# In regular expressions, what's the difference between [:blank:], [:space:], and \s-?

Tags: regular-expressions, syntax

I've been playing around with `rx` lately, and I just noticed there are (at least) 3 different ways of indicating whitespaces in regular expressions.

1. `[:blank:]`
2. `[:space:]`
3. `\s-`

What are the differences between each of them? Does it depend on the major-mode?

Comment: [***What does Emacs say?***](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html)  ([`[:space:]` and `\s-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table) are the same.) `C-h i`, Elisp manual, `C-s [:space]`.

Comment: "Playing around" `;)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[:blank:]` character class matches only the SPC and TAB characters. The other two match whitespace based on the active syntax table.

There does not seem to be a difference between `[:space:]` and `\s-`. The latter is an instance of the general **\s*code*** pattern for matching based on a syntax class.

Comment: Just did a quick test modifying the syntax table in a buffer to make additional characters whitespace. Testing with `regexp-builder` I can confirm that both `[:space:]` and `\s-` match the additional characters as spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the detailed difference for yourself with the following code:

```lisp
(defun me/chars-in-class (class)
  "return a list of chars in char class `class`"
  (let ((chars nil))
    (dotimes (i 65536) ;; the absolute upperbound is 4194304 (22 bit integer) according to elisp info, but you will not find any chars in :space:/:blank:/\s- beyond the usual bound 65536
      (when (string-match-p class (char-to-string i))
        (push i chars)))
    chars))

(let* ((charlist1 (sort (me/chars-in-class "[[:blank:]]") '<)) ;; make a char list of :blank:
       (charlist2 (sort (me/chars-in-class "[[:space:]]") '<)) ;; make a char list of :space:
       (charlist3 (sort (me/chars-in-class "\\s-") '<)) ;; make a char list of \s-
       (set-list
        (sort (cl-remove-duplicates (append charlist1 charlist2 charlist3)) '<)) ;; make a "set" list with all the chars from :blank:, :space:, and \s-, without duplicates
       trio)
  (cl-loop for e in set-list
       for i from 0
       if (equal i 0)
       collect '("blank" "space" "\\s-")
       and collect 'hline
       do (setq trio nil)
       (if (equal e (car charlist3))
           (push (pop charlist3) trio)
         (push nil trio))
       (if (equal e (car charlist2))
           (push (pop charlist2) trio)
         (push nil trio))
       (if (equal e (car charlist1))
           (push (pop charlist1) trio)
         (push nil trio))
       collect trio))
```

If executed in a org mode source block, the above code compares side by side in a table all the chars, or rather their unicode code point ("char number"), in the three char classes in question:

```
| blank | space |   \s- |
|-------+-------+-------|
|     9 |     9 |     9 |
|   nil |    10 |    10 |
|   nil |    12 |    12 |
|   nil |    13 |    13 |
|    32 |    32 |    32 |
|   160 |   160 |   160 |
|  5760 |   nil |   nil |
|  8192 |  8192 |  8192 |
|  8193 |  8193 |  8193 |
|  8194 |  8194 |  8194 |
|  8195 |  8195 |  8195 |
|  8196 |  8196 |  8196 |
|  8197 |  8197 |  8197 |
|  8198 |  8198 |  8198 |
|  8199 |  8199 |  8199 |
|  8200 |  8200 |  8200 |
|  8201 |  8201 |  8201 |
|  8202 |  8202 |  8202 |
|   nil |  8203 |  8203 |
|  8239 |  8239 |  8239 |
|  8287 |  8287 |  8287 |
| 12288 | 12288 | 12288 |
```

So first, :space: and `\s-` are completely the same.

Then, what :space: has but :blank: doesn't have are the chars 10, 12, 13, and 8203 (newline, formfeed character, carriage return, and zero width space), what :blank: has but :space: doesn't have is the single char 5760 (Ogham space mark). For the rest part, they are the same, both in particular sharing the common elements SPC and TAB.